# Writing a loop to generate new series of graphs in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, plotly

I am trying to create a series of dashboards with nearly 12 graphs per institution based on one dataset. I have made a set of graphs for one institution, and I need to do the same for nearly 300 more institutions. Is there a way to just write a for loop in plotly or just in python in general, so that the series of graphs can change based on the institution (origin) name?

What I have been doing so far is writing this line:

```
    origin_df = new_df.loc[new_df['origin']=='Institution1']
```

and then saving those graphs, and then replacing `'Instituion1'` with `'Institution2'`

I just wonder if there is an easier way to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't get too discouraged, @Deeda -- it is standard practice to remove "Thanks" from questions, e.g. [see this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Most editors do it (including me!). I guess the idea is that there are concrete ways to say "Thanks", using upvotes etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Try this:

```
for institution, inst_df in new_df.groupby('origin'):
    ⋮
    <do make plots for this institution>
    ⋮
```

Each time around the loop, `institution` is one of the unique values in the `origin` column, and `inst_df` is a new dataframe containing the rows matching that unique value.